# RxJava. Convert hot observable of list to single item stream, process it and convert to list back

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

Assuming i have a **hot** observable of lists of some items;

```
Observable<List<Item>> observable = ...;
```

I need to convert it to single items stream and perform some operation on each item, like filtering, after that i should convert it back to list and process it in `onNext` method of subscriber:

```
observable.flatMap(Observable::from)
    .filter(Item::isFiltered)
    .toList()
    .subscribe(this::onNext, this::onError)

public void onNext(List<Item> items) {...}
```

From the first look it seems ok, but it isn't, because our observable is **hot**, so toList() won't be ever executed (because it waits for source observable completion) and whole stream stucks.

How can i resolve this problem? Also please note that near the `filter` could be any amount of additional operations over single item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do all of your operations on single items and your final `toList` operator on the Observable you create in `flatMap` .. That way, you receive onComplete call and `toList` will collect and transform the items.

```
observable.flatMap(list -> {
     return Observable.from(list)
                        .filter(Item::isFiltered)
                        .toList()
  })
  .subscribe(this::onNext, this::onError)
```